# how to clear sidx & sord parameters when clicked on reload grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I was using jqGrid.I have implemented multiple column search, through search toolbar (completely handled on server side) and using virtual scrolling to load records.But when i click on reload  grid automatically all search fields in the prams vanishes so no problem with that but the value of sort column remains i.e sidx & sord.So when i click on reload grid instead of getting fresh records i was getting records being sorted.Is there a way to handle this....?

```
           jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid({
                    url: 'http://localhost:7887/application/get',
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames: ['AppId', 'Name', 'Rank'],
                    colModel: [
                        {name: 'AppId', key: true, width: 80,search: true, searchoptions: { searchOperators: true, sopt: ['gt', 'eq','lt'],} },
                        { name: 'Name', width: 150, search: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'ew','cn'] } },
                        { name: 'Rank', width: 350, search: true },
                    ],
                    width: 800,
                    rowNum: 100,
                    height: 180,
                    scroll: 1,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    loadonce:false,
                    caption: "Loading data while scrolling",
                    onSelectRow: jqGrid_RowSelectd,
                    emptyrecords:"there are no records to display",
                    pager:"#gridpager"
                });

                $("#jqgrid").filterToolbar({ autosearch: true, searchOperators: true, sopt: ['gt', 'eq'] });
                $("#jqgrid").navGrid('#gridpager', { del: false, add: false, edit: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true });
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `beforeRefresh` as the option of `navGrid`. So you can do the following

```js
$("#jqgrid").navGrid('#gridpager', { del: false, add: false, edit: false,
    beforeRefresh: function () {
        var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");
        p.sortname = "";
        p.sortorder = "asc";
    }
}, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true });
```

Comment: at this condition during grid reload  i want to disable the sortable icons ,i tried to select it through its ( css class of that icons) for a particular column and hide it.Is there any better way that jqgrid offers to turn off sort icons after grid reload..@Oleg

Comment: @Ein2012: You are welcome! I'm not sure what you mean with sortable icons. If you use `sortable: false` property for some column then no icon should be in the column and the cursor will be default. Nothing more one need to do, at least in free jqGrid.